# Sublime's CTRL + R in PHPStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, sublimetext

I would like to search in all the methods of a specific class in `PHPStorm` like I can do in Sublime using `CTRL + R`.

Is there such a feature in `PHPStorm`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## [Navigating with Structure Views](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/navigating-with-structure-views.html)

In [[image]phpstorm](/questions/tagged/phpstorm) this feature have named as **File Structure**, shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>(<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> on OS X).

And quickly perform search by **[Speed Search](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/speed-search-in-the-tool-windows.html)**.

[image]

Use this feature in any files: `*.html`, `*.css`, `*.sql`, etc.